# Java: Copy textfile content to another without replacing

Tags: java, eclipse, filereader, filewriter

I want to take the content of one text file chosen by the user and add it to another text file without replacing the current content. So for example:

Update: How do I add it to the second file in a numbered way?

TextFile1:

AAA BBB CCC

AAA BBB CCC

TextFile2: (After copying)

1. EEE FFF GGG
2. AAA BBB CCC
3. AAA BBB CCC

Update: I had to remove my code as it may be taken for plagiarism, This was answered so I know what to do, thanks for everyone helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
You have to use

```
new FileWriter(fileName,append);
```

This opens the file in append mode:

According to the javadoc it says

Parameters:
fileName String The system-dependent filename.

append boolean if true, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReader Read = null;
    FileWriter Import = null;
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
        System.out.flush();
        String filename = scanner.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);
        Read = new FileReader(filename);
        Import = new FileWriter("songstuff.txt",true);
        int Rip = Read.read();

        while(Rip!=-1) {
            Import.write(Rip);
            Rip = Read.read();
        }


    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(Read);
        close(Import);
    }
}


public static void close(Closeable stream) {
    try {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
       // JavaProgram();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `new FileWriter("songstuff.txt", true);` to append to the file instead of overwriting it.

Refer : [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache commons IO.

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class HelpTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        String inputFilename = "test.txt"; // get from the user

        //Im loading file from project
        //You might load from somewhere else...
        URI uri = HelpTest.class.getResource("/" + inputFilename).toURI();
        String fileString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(uri));

        // output file
        File outputFile = new File("C:\\test.txt");
        FileUtils.write(outputFile, fileString, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Append the file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

```
new FileWriter(fileName,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A file channel that is open for writing may be in append mode .. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html

also have a look at ..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File, boolean)